# Should I call attention to rude users and comments? If so, how?

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments, flagging

Recently, I answered a question and, apparently partly misunderstood the OP. I say 'apparently' because the OP proceeded to bite my head off in a comment and ask for a downvote. They were even more rude to another answer by a user who apparently misunderstood the same aspect of the question I did.

Should I flag users and/or comments like these for moderator attention? If so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, flagging comments is acceptable for abusive statements. I have included a comment to your post so you can see how this is done. If you hover your mouse over the comment, you will see a little flag icon. Hit it to flag the comment.

And as @Aarthi mentioned in the comment, please don't respond to rudeness with rudeness. It just never ends well, for anyone involved. We mods have the tools required to properly manage the situation, without making it worse. And hopefully the level head to execute such tools.

Comment: As an addendum: *avoid responding* to rudeness yourself! That often exacerbates a tense situation. Allowing mods to handle the issue is a far better option, in our opinion.

Comment: @Aarthi as in, do not feed the troll? Thanks for the advice! :)