# Are there guidelines for specific question types or references to review before asking a question?

Tags: discussion, faq

Is there a list of **Frequently Asked Questions** or common guideline questions which users can refer to with ease?

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no one location to view common informational posts/questions. However, here is a list of some general links to helpful common meta posts, guidelines, community wiki questions, and general resources, in an effort to cull them all into a single location.

---

### Critique Guidelines

[What are the guidelines for asking for a critique of my work?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work)

---

### Font Identification Guidelines

[What are the requirements for font identification questions?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/guidelines-for-font-identification-questions)

---

### Rules for Chat

[What Are The Rules For Chat?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/what-are-the-rules-for-chat)

---

### PPI/DPI Resolution Wiki

[I need to print an image at a certain size. What dimensions and resolution should I use?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/i-need-to-print-an-image-a-certain-size-what-dimensions-and-resolutions-should)

---

### Stock Photo Resources

[Where are some good places to find royalty free stock images?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115/where-are-some-good-places-to-find-royalty-free-stock-images)

---

### Typeface Resources

[Where do professional designers "go" to look for typefaces?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15926/where-do-professional-designers-go-to-look-for-typefaces)

---

### Good Subjective/Bad Subjective

[Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

---

### Design tips for beginning designers

[Tips and resources for beginning designers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-resources-for-beginning-designers)

---

### Pricing Strategy

[What price should I charge for design services?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/957/what-price-should-i-charge-for-design-services)

---

Comment: I **encourage** others to edit this and add anything I may be missing.