# Who should be the Ink Spot room owners and what should their role be?

Tags: discussion, faq, chat

[The Ink Spot's](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) [room owners](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1240/the-ink-spot?tab=access) have previously been chosen without an officially established criteria and their role left undecided. How should they be appointed and what responsibilities should that position include?

Comment: I'd like to think that the previous owners weren't chosen without rhyme or reason, they were all regular attendees of the chat room

Comment: @Zach recently yes, but previous to that there were a few users who hadn't been in chat for over a year. [Jack](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/672/jack?tab=profile) was the original room owner and remained so for quite a long time despite moving on from the site.

Comment: Thanks JohnB for taking the time to write this up

Answer (score 8):

We'd like to appoint individuals who have hung around a while, maintain recent activity, and who uphold themselves in good standing with the community to be room owners for The Ink Spot. Admittedly, this is incredibly subjective, but we do not want to base this on objective requisites to be gamed. If you think you or someone else is deserving of the role, ask for feedback in the chat!

The #1 priority for *all* participants should be ensuring that chat is a friendly environment for all. Since chat room owners have increased abilities, they should assist with making sure the [rules for chat](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/605/8708) are enforced. Since not all users will be familiar with those rules, we would prefer a soft-handed approach. If someone is misbehaving, a friendly reminder should be the first course of action. Let them know that they're breaking etiquette and offer a link to the rules.

It is exceedingly rare for our chat room to have incidents that require any elevated moderation. Special actions such as editing/deleting other users messages or kick-muting users should only be used as a last resort and for serious infractions. Please tread lightly; a prolonged period of inactivity or abuse of powers may be cause for removal from the position.

---

Currently we've appointed 4 users into this role:

- Scott
- Joojaa
- Zach Saucier
- Yisela

If anyone has a concern or issue with these users having the RO status please ping one of the mods and we can setup a private chat to discuss. If you feel you should also be given the RO status ping us and we can discuss that as well.

Comment: As with all policies, this is open to community input. This is what the mods agreed upon after internal discussion. If you think either of these points should be handled differently, I encourage you to post your thoughts as an answer to this question.

Comment: I hadn't seen this. Thanks!